# Variant type causes heap corruption

Tags: c++, variant, heap-corruption

I just tried to move a C++ project from Windows XP to Windows 7 (make it run in win7).

the compile is OK however the application crashes as soon as reach the following code (The code is a piece of example code, but it has same issue).

```
void Test(const BSTR& b)
{
     _variant_t t;
     t.vt = VT_BSTR;
     t.bstrVal = b;
}

int main()
{
    const BSTR b = L"Test"; 
    Test(b);
｝
```

The code is working fine in windows XP but in Windows 7 a heap corruption occurs.

If I change the code from

```
_variant_t t;
t.vt = VT_BSTR;
t.bstrVal = b;
```

to

```
_variant_t t(b);
```

then it works fine on windows 7.

My Question, why the first piece of code is not working on Windows 7?

Comment: Can you post more details about the exception you're getting

Comment: Windows has triggered a breakpoint in test.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in KioskGetDiskFreeSpace.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

Comment: I use VS Studio 2010 compile the code.